# Как на jQuery сделать подгрузку новых строк в таблицу?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Допустим, есть вот такой код. При нажатии на ссылку, должен отправляться ajax запрос. Получение данных может занимать достаточно много времени, за которое очень просто успеть нажать еще 1-2 ссылки. Учитывая, что $.ajax работает асинхронно, возникает вопрос. А как передать в error и success коллбэки ссылку на элемент, по клику на котором была запущена загрузка данных?

```js
$(function(){

  $('table tr').on('click', 'td>a', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().after('<tr>'
    +'<td>Additional row</td>'
    +'<td>Some data...</td>'
    +'<td>Some data...</td>'
   +'</tr>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Load additional rows</a></td>
    <td>Some data...</td>
    <td>Some data...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Load additional rows</a></td>
    <td>Some data...</td>
    <td>Some data...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Load additional rows</a></td>
    <td>Some data...</td>
    <td>Some data...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Load additional rows</a></td>
    <td>Some data...</td>
    <td>Some data...</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: "отправляться ajax запрос" - где?

Comment: @Igor должен отправляться != отправляется. Представьте, что переметр, который передается в after был получен с помощью ajax. Я не прошу писать за меня код, меня интересует лишь способ связать объект с асинхронным коллбэком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success: (function(data){ 
  // "this" here is target element of click event
}).bind(this),
```